# eloquent relationships and information about the parent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hello I´m starting with laravel and I want to generate a list
of makes and its models.

For example:

Ford: Mustang, Expedition

GMC: Denali

These are my tables:

```
makes
    - id
    - name

models
    - id
    - name
    - make_id
```

I added

```
public function models()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Make');
}
```

to the Make model and after that I can use

```
$models = Make::find(1)->models;
```

That returns the list of models (but no information about the make)
and I also need to get all makes and its models not just 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this snippet of code:

```php
public function models()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Make');
}
```

with

```php
public function models()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model');
}
```

Comment: In order to retrieve all the models use with statement: Make::all()->with('models');